# Split indirect question

Tags: grammar, questions

Here's a direct question.

> Where does he live?

And here's an indirect one.

> Do you know *where he lives*?

I wonder how you would analyze the following structure. Can we call it "a split indirect question/noun clause"?

> *Where* do you think *he lives*?

Comment: Please define what you mean by indirect question.

Comment: @Lambie: an embedded question

Comment: Right, Thanks. For me, "Do you know where he lives?" is not an embedded ot indirect question. The question is composed of the question element: "Do you know" followed by dependent clause with the word where introducing it. –

Comment: @Lambie: "We can ask a question indirectly by putting it into a sub-clause beginning with a question word or with _if/whether_. This makes the question sound less abrupt. _We need to know what the rules are. Could you tell me where Queen Street is, please? Do you know when the train gets in?_" John Eastwood, _Oxford Learner's Grammar_, p. 26 "We can ask an **indirect question** by putting it into a **subordinate** CLAUSE beginning with a WH-WORD or with _if_ or _whether_ (e.g. Can you tell me _where you live_?)." Martin Hewings, _Advanced Grammar in Use_, p. 215

Comment: As I said, there is nothing indirect in "Do you know [etc.]. The fact the sub-clause has other information does not make it indirect, regardless of what Brainly says. **Can you tell me* where you live? It is  interrogative because of "Can you tell me [etc.]" not because of "where you live".

Comment: However, I said to him , "do you know where he lives" change into indirect speech.​ (from Brainly) becomes in indirect **speech**: Do  you know where he lives? That is called indirect speech or reported speech.

Comment: Can you please respond to my last two comments? Thanks.

Comment: @Lambie: "The example comes from Brainly, I think." They're my own examples and explanations. More reference works where such questions are classified as _indirect questions_: "_Can you tell me whether or not you’re interested in the job?_" [If and whether: indirect questions - Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/if-or-whether) "All the **wh-** words (including **whether**) can introduce INDIRECT QUESTIONS. _Can you tell me **what the time is**, please?_" Geoffrey Leech, _An A-Z of English Grammar & Usage_, p. 578

Comment: Your link says this: We can use if or whether to report indirect yes-no questions and questions with or. If is more common than whether. That is neither of yours. It would have to be: Do you know if/whether he lives here? For example.

Comment: 'Where do you think he lives?' is semantically equivalent to 'Where does he live, in your opinion?' It's (as Lambie says) a direct question (soliciting a response from the addressee); it's complicated by a modal-licensing hedge (where 'modal' here means 'pertaining to / using a qualification regarding speaker uncertainty').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Do you know where he lives?*, the subclause *where he lives?* is called an [indirect question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause#Interrogative_content_clauses) because (a) it is an interrogative clause but (b) it is not directly put to someone. So, just to be clear, it is not the question *Do you know where he lives?* that is the indirect question, it is specifically the subclause.

*Where do you think he lives?* is a direct question (in the sense that it is directly put to someone) which happens to be complex syntactically (i.e., consist of a matrix clause with predicate *think* and a subordinate clause with predicate *live*). The Wh-element has been [moved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement) from the subordinate to the matrix clause, but this is entirely separate from the direct–indirect question type.

Comment: I'd say: Where does he live? is a direct question... so is your example but why complicate it? Because to make yours indirect, you have to say: Where did he say he thought he lived?

Comment: @Lambie all examples I'm using are taken directly from the question. The specific question Mori asked was how to classify *Where do you think he lives?* -- that's why I "used that example".

Comment: I just don't see it as indirect. Do you know where he lives? can be addressed to someone directly.

Comment: @Lambie indeed. As I wrote, it is the subordinate clause that is an indirect question.

Comment: I think this OP is confusing direct and indirect speech. Not questions. The example comes from Brainly, I think.

Comment: @Lambie if you want to know what the OP means, better take it up with them than with me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is the following a similar case, and basically a grammatical structure? _Where, I wonder, he lives._

Comment: @Mori I'm not a native speaker, but *Where, I wonder, he lives* does not look like a grammatical main clause to me. You can get *Where, I wonder, does he live?* (cf. [*Where, I wonder, should I have been ...?*](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/7330839)). This is a direct question with a parenthetical (*I wonder*), hence the structure should be that of a direct question with do-support (*Where does he live?* rather than *Where he lives?*).